# select elements within a loop R

Tags: r, list, for-loop

Ive tried trawling through forums for answer to this but cant find it.
I want to scroll through the unique values of a dataframe column (IN_FID) and add the values from another column (NEAR_FID) associated with that value (there may be one or multiple) to a list.  The IN_FID then gets added to a list.  If the values in NEAR_FID have been seen before during this process then the IN_FID does not get added to the list.  I know I havent included it in the code but ideally I would also like to loop through the IN_FID values at random instead of sequentially.
What am I doing wrong in this code?

```
eagle
   IN_FID NEAR_FID
1       2        1
2       2        2
3       2        3
4       8        4
5       9        2
6       9        7
7       9        8
8       9        9
9      16        2
10     16       11
11     21       12

p.good = list()
p.bad = list()
INFIDS = unique(eagle$IN_FID)
NEARFIDS = unique(eagle$NEAR_FID)
t.used = NEARFIDS

for (i in INFIDS) {
sub = eagle[eagle$IN_FID == i, ]
x = sub$NEAR_FID
if (all(x) %in% t.used){
    p.good = c(p.good, i)
    t.used[t.used != all(x)]

} else { 
    p.bad = c(p.bad, i)
}
```

The desired output would be:

```
p.good
[1] 2 8 21  (because NEAR_FID of 2 is present in 9 and 16)
p.bad
[1] 9 16
t.used
= empty because it will have used the values during the loop
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `all()`? There might be other issues as well, but that one stood out to me.

Comment: Can you also provide the desired output for this input so that possible solutions can be tested?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the fact that x varies in size and it doesnt remove x from t.used when x contains more than one value

Comment: Don't check that `all(x)` is in `t.used`. Check that `all(x %in% t.used)` (if that's what you're trying to do - I'm still pretty confused about your process).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the function `duplicated()`

```
index_dup = which(duplicated(eagle$NEAR_FID))

p.bad = unique(eagle$IN_FID[index_dup])

index_bad = c()
for (i in p.bad){
  index_bad = c(index_bad,which(eagle$IN_FID == i))
}

p.good = unique(eagle$IN_FID[-index_bad])
```

For the randomisation, you could random the row order of your data then apply the code above again

```
eagle_random <- eagle[sample(1:nrow(eagle)), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a list, declare as `vector`:

```
p.good = NULL
p.bad = NULL

INFIDS = unique(eagle$IN_FID)
NEARFIDS = unique(eagle$NEAR_FID)
t.used = NEARFIDS
```

Instead of `min:max`, iterate through elements of vector `for (i in INFIDS)`:

```
for (i in INFIDS) {
     x = (eagle %>% filter(IN_FID == i))$NEAR_FID   # combine into single statement
     if (all(x %in% t.used)) {    # was all(x) %in% t.used before
        p.good = c(p.good, i)
        t.used = t.used[!(t.used %in% x)]  # was t.used != all(x)
    } else {
        p.bad = c(p.bad, i)  
    }
}
```

Output:

```
p.good
[1] 2  8 21

p.bad
[1] 9 16

t.used
[1] 7  8  9 11    # some values were not eliminated as you expected
```

----**random sampling**----

Change `for (i in INFIDS)`

To `for (i in sample(INFIDS))`. Use `set.seed(1)` to control random sampling.